# Trying to define namespace member via using-declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, definition, using-declaration

Consider the following program. Is it well-formed or not according to the c++ standard (references to relevant parts of the standard needed):

```
namespace X { extern int i; }

namespace N { using X::i; }

int N::i = 1;

int main() {}
```

I'm getting different results for different compilers. I'm trying to figure out for what compiler I should file a bug report for:

- Clang: Gives the following compiler error: No member named 'i' in namespace 'N'
- GCC and Visual C++ compiles it without errors.

For comparison the following gives compiler error with all three compilers:

```
namespace X { void f(); }

namespace N { using X::f; }

void N::f() {};

int main() {}
```

Comment: Funny, VS2013 compiles, but IntelliSence says `"Error: namespace "N" has no actual member "i"`

Comment: I think the answer is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175705/scope-of-using-declaration-within-a-namespace)

Comment: @Supremum You can get your own copy of the C++ standard to read at https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard.

Comment: Jorj Tyron: That link does not answer this question. This question is not about best practices.

Comment: @Supremum I got it working with CLang by changing "using X::i" to "using namespace X;".

Comment: VS2013 compiles but in editor says *Error: namespace "N" has no actual member "i"* ! Same for you @AlexD? What VS2013 version do you have?

Comment: @JorjTyron `VS Professional 2013,  Version 12.0.21005.1 REL`

Comment: @Supremum Have you reported this for MSVC, by any chance?

Comment: @bogdan: I have reported 12 bugs to clang 15 bugs to gcc (not counting some rejected ones). If you search for Anders Granlund as reporter in the bugzilla pages for clang and gcc you will find them. Some of them, like this one exists in MSVC also, but I have not made any reports to MSVC. Feel free to do that if you want to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Current working draft N4527, [8.3p1]:

> [...] When the *declarator-id* is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a
>   previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the
>   qualifier refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the
>   inline namespace set of that namespace (7.3.1)) or to a specialization
>   thereof; the member shall not merely have been introduced by a
>   *using-declaration* in the scope of the class or namespace nominated by
>   the *nested-name-specifier* of the *declarator-id*. [...]

So, definitely ill-formed; GCC and MSVC are wrong.