# Example of error caused by using directive in namespaces

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, using-directives, using-declaration

I'm trying to understand what kind of errors could arise from including `using` declarations in namespaces. I'm taking into account [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175705/scope-of-using-declaration-within-a-namespace) [links](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/053.htm).

I'm trying to create an example where an error is being caused by a name being silently replaced by an header file being loaded before another one, due to usage of the `using` declaration.

Here I'm defining `MyProject::vector`:

```
// base.h
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

namespace MyProject
{
    class vector {};
}

#endif
```

This is the "bad" header: here I'm trying to trick `using` into shadowing other possible definitions of `vector` inside `MyNamespace`:

```
// x.h
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

#include <vector>

namespace MyProject
{
    // With this everything compiles with no error!
    //using namespace std;

    // With this compilation breaks!
    using std::vector;
}

#endif
```

This is the unsuspecting header trying to use `MyProject::vector` as defined in `base.h`:

```
// z.h
#ifndef Z_H
#define Z_H

#include "base.h"

namespace MyProject
{
    void useVector()
    {
        const vector v;
    }
}

#endif
```

And finally here's the implementation file, including both `x.h` and `z.h`:

```
// main.cpp
// If I swap these two, program compiles!
#include "x.h"
#include "z.h"

int main()
{
    MyProject::useVector();
}
```

If I include `using std::vector` in `x.h`, an actual compilation error happens, telling me that I must specify a template argument when using `vector` in `z.h`, because `x.h` successfully managed to shadow the definition of `vector` inside `MyProject`. Is this a good example of why `using` declarations shouldn't be used in header files, or things go deeper that this, and I'm missing much more?

If I include `using namespace std` in `x.h`, however, the shadowing doesn't occur, and the program compiles just fine. Why is that? Shouldn't `using namespace std` load all names visible under `std`, including `vector`, thus shadowing the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I include using namespace std in x.h, however, the shadowing
>   doesn't occur, and the program compiles just fine. Why is that?

This much I can answer from 7.3.4/2-3:

First

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
>   the using-directive.

Then followed up:

> A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative region
>   in which it appears.

So a using-directive (`using namespace`) only makes the names usable from the target namespace, it does not make them members of it. So any existing member will be preferred over the used namespace member.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this distinction between the two usage of `using`.