# Name conflicts not detected when using aliases

Tags: c++, alias, shadowing, using-declaration

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799873/example-of-error-caused-by-using-directive-in-namespaces). Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MyProject {
    class string {
        public: string() { std::cout << "Callin string constructor" << std::endl; }
    };
}

namespace Other {
    class string {};
}

namespace MyProject {
    using Other::string;
}

namespace MyProject {
    void useString() {
        const string s;
    }
}

int main() {
    MyProject::useString();
}
```

Here the compiler correctly throws an error at the line `using Other::string`, complaining that a declaration for `string` already exists in that namespace, coming from the previous `class string` definition.

Now consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MyProject {
    class string {
        public: string() { std::cout << "Callin string constructor" << std::endl; }
    };
}

namespace Other {
    class something {};
    using string = something;
}

namespace MyProject {
    using Other::string;
}

namespace MyProject {
    void useString() {
        const string s;
    }
}

int main() {
    MyProject::useString();
}
```

Here there's no compilation error: I successfully managed to shadow my previous declaration of `string` with a new one.

- Why there's no error in the second case? Is it because `using string = something` is not an actual *declaration*, since it's an alias and the real declaration is for the `something` name, and the compiler can only spot conflicts between actual declarations, so in this case it would think that I'm really declaring `something` and `string`, and be ok with that?
- Isn't this quite dangerous? I mean, if these things happen in separate header files without the programmer realizing it, s/he could end up using an identifier that may be something completely different than what s/he thinks, and without the compiler saying anything...

Comment: Which compiler/version? Clang 3.8+ rejects this code as ambiguous (not on the `using` but when declaring `const string s`).

Comment: @Holt good point, I tested this on g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: vc++ also accepts the code. Looks like all major compilers are wrong, see 7.3.3/13 "Since a using-declaration is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same
declarative region (3.3) also apply to using-declarations."