# How to use a user defined literal in a header file?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, user-defined-literals

I have defined the following user-defined literal in `MyLiteral.h`:

```
namespace my_literals {
    constexpr uint64_t operator"" _nanoseconds(unsigned long long int value) {
        return value*1000;
    }
}
```

Now I could use the operator in another header `SomeComponent.h`:

```
using namespace my_literals;
namespace foo {
    constexpr uint64_t timeout = 10_nanoseconds;
}
```

However, I don't want to pollute the scope by `using namespace my_literals`, because this would provide the literal definition to all `*.cpp` files which include `SomeComponent.h`.

How can I avoid this? `constexpr uint64_t timeout = my_literals::10_nanoseconds;` gives *expected unqualified-id before numeric constant* in g++.

Comment: Sorry, I reopened because the duplicate answer did not have the constraint of being in a header file, but it turns out the solution is the same either way. I reclosed it as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate at all. It is a more constrained case of the alleged duplicate, and requires different solutions. The accepted answer (and only one at this point) in the other question uses a scope and a `using namespace` declaration that cannot be used in a header.

Answer (score 15):

In C++17, with constexpr lambda, you may do:

```
namespace foo {
    constexpr uint64_t timeout = []{ using namespace my_literals; return 10_nanoseconds; }();
}
```

as alternative to (C++11 and higher):

```
namespace foo {
    constexpr uint64_t timeout = my_literals::operator""_nanoseconds(10);
}
```

or

```
namespace foo {

    namespace detail
    {
        using namespace my_literals;
        constexpr uint64_t timeout = 10_nanoseconds;
    }
    using detail::timeout;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get around this by calling the operator explicitly:

```
namespace foo {
    constexpr uint64_t timeout = my_literals::operator""_nanoseconds(10);
}
```

Comment: Extremely ugly :)

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg No doubt. It's fine for library code though.

Comment: I can confirm this works and comprises my intention. However, it is obviously ugly and no longer an intuitive literal.

Comment: @Alexander By the way, why don't you use `std::chrono` utilities?

Comment: 1) I am on a constrained embedded system which tightly integrates with an RTOS and its own definition of time. 2) I was unaware of `std::chrono` and will take a look. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: namespace foo
    {
     using namespace my_literals;
     constexpr uint64_t timeout = 10_nanoseconds;
    }
this should also work - easier to read.

Comment: @Tunichtgut: you miss OP's point, as then, after `using namespace foo;` you can do `10_nanosecond`.

Comment: In this case why even use literals? There are many old pre - c++11 methods which would look more elegant than this.

Comment: @vsz I assumed this was library code and the `using namespace` is not supposed to be leaked to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `using` declaration inside the namespace (if you don't mind having `foo::operator""_nanoseconds` available):

```
namespace foo {
    using namespace my_literals;
    constexpr uint64_t timeout = 10_nanoseconds;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mind and here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175705/scope-of-using-declaration-within-a-namespace

Comment: @Alexander Interesting...