# Variable is ambiguous when using namespaces c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Coordinates.h

```
namespace Coordinates
{
    class Coordinates
    {
    public:
        Coordinates(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    };
}
```

Tile.h

```
#include "Coordinates.h"
#include <vector>

namespace Tile
{
    using namespace Coordinates;

    class Tile
    {
    private:
        std::vector <Coordinates> coordTile;
    };
}
```

On the second header Tile.h, it says at `std::vector <Coordinates> coordTile;` that `Tile::Coordinates` is ambiguous. Without namespaces the program doesn't give any error.

Comment: The ambiguity is because you named the class the same thing as the namespace. This is easy to avoid if you use CamelCase for classes and everythinginlowercase for namespaces.

Comment: `using namespace Coordinates;` in a header.  very bad idea

Comment: Without `using namespace` it shouldn't compile at all...

Comment: @UKMonkey • it's less bad (but still something I'd discourage) when it is done within another namespace.

Comment: I would suggest your namespace might be simplified further if you just put them both into "MyGraphicsLib" ; if you have 1 namespace / class then you kinda defeat the point of namespaces

Comment: Because of the name collision, you'll have to disambiguate it:  `std::vector <::Coordinates::Coordinates> coordTile;`

Comment: @MaxLanghof I see, it works. I have a lot of classes with a lot of headers, would be ideal if I don't use ```using namespace namespaceName;``` in the headers and write the whole name like in this case: coordinates::Coordinates ? And use it only in the .cpp files?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu As UKMonkey said, don't use one namespace per class because that's pointless. Namespaces _group_ classes (and other names)

Comment: @Eljay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175705/scope-of-using-declaration-within-a-namespace

Comment: Even in your .cpp files, I urge you not to pull in an entire namespace.  Pull in explicitly just the symbols you use, and nothing else.

Comment: Someone adviced me to wrap my classes in it's own namespace to avoid nameclashes. But if I don't use ```using namespace name;``` the code gets harder to read because the length of the lines get a lot bigger ex: ```x::x::A```.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu "Someone adviced me to wrap my classes in it's own namespace"  I think that was some mis-communication; it should be in "A namespace" - maybe.  There's nothing wrong with the global namespace for smaller projects at all

Comment: @UKMonkey "You should wrap all your functions and classes in its own namespace to prevent nameclashes." Does that mean that all functions and classes should be in a single namespace ? Or every class should have a namespace? I never used namespaces before, I'm not sure how this is done. I though that I need to use a namespace on every class like my example.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu "Does that mean that all functions and classes should be in a single namespace?"  no - because that would again defeat the point of namespaces.  However, you might want to put all YOUR functions and classes into a single namespace.  It's done by just replacing `namespace Coordinates` and `namespace Tile` with `namespace MyThings`  (and deleting the `using`)

Comment: @UKMonkey done it put all classes and functions in a single namespace, and it works and makes so much sense, now I see what he meant by use a namespace. Glad I asked this question, thanks. One more thing, I know ```using namespace std;``` is a bad practice and I shouldn't use it. Should I use and include ```std::cout``` ```std::cin``` ```std::vector`` etc. or just use std:: everywhere?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu putting `using std::cout` at the top of your cpp file or using `std::cout` every time are the 2 safest options... as it ensures you don't bring in more than you need.  You can also put `using` within functions if you want; so if you want to bring in the whole of std just for that 1 function because it uses a lot of std things.... (then maybe use a smaller function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a namespace `Coordinates`, and a class `Coordinates`, and due to your use of `using namespace` both names are in scope. Although a vector element type cannot be a namespace, this is still an ambiguity at that particular phase of compilation.

Your class `Coordinates` does not need to be in a namespace `Coordinates` at all. Good advice is to put all your code into a namespace to "shield" it from other peoples' code — you may wish to further organise your code into multiple namespaces, but there is no benefit in putting each class in its own namespace, and certainly you shouldn't re-use their names like this.

Comment: I understood from reading the comments that what I was trying to do was wrong and  I shouldn't wrap each class in its own namespace. Also should't use same name for namespaces and classes. Thanks

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu Yes the information & solutions given in the comments should have been posted as answers instead.