# Scope of a namespace specified?

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

What is the scope of a namespace that is specified in a using directive outside of all functions?

Comment: Duplicate: [What's the scope of the “using” declaration in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/223021/1227469)

Comment: In particular, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/223250/1227469)